# LowLevelKeyboardProc and KeyboardProc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-hook

What is the difference between `LowLevelKeyboardProc` and `KeyboardProc`? I'm beginner in win hooks and only had read hooks overview at microsoft site so, please, explain me as understandable as posible :-)

Comment: When you ask questions like this that request explanation of a concept, it is helpful to point out (with links if an online resource) what resources you've read on the topic. You said you read an overview on hooks, but did you read anything about those two in particular? Was there something specific in them that you didn't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, ...);` will capture events directly from the keyboard driver or simulated keyboard events.  `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, ...);` captures events after they have been processed by the OS.

There is an OS enforced time limit for processing Low Level events and Microsoft recommends you do minimal processing on the event itself and schedule any significant work to a different thread so that the operation of the driver is not interrupted.

The higher level events include the repeat count and there is no time limit for processing the event.